# Why do [^ -~] and [^\\u0000-\\u007f] match differently?

Tags: r, regex

I'm struggling to understand why `[^ -~]` and `[^\\u0000-\\u007f]` seem to not match in exactly the same way. Both character classes (should) match non-ASCII characters. Suppose we have this vector:

```
txt <- c("New York 234", "Delhi Στις Τρί", "腹热小天تن", "über den Wolken", "down the straße")
```

Used with `grep` the two classes produce different results:

```
grep("[^ -~]", txt, value = T)
[1] "Delhi Στις Τρί"  "腹热小天تن"      "über den Wolken" "down the straße"
grep("[^\\u0000-\\u007f]", txt, value = T) ###???
[1] "New York 234"    "Delhi Στις Τρί"  "腹热小天تن"      "über den Wolken" "down the straße"
```

The string `New York 234` is matched by `[^\\u0000-\\u007f]` although it does contain ASCII characters. This is all the more surprising since the *un-negated* character classes clearly do detect the ASCII characters in the strings as shown by `str_extract` operations:

```
 unlist(str_extract_all(txt, "[ -~]"))
 [1] "N" "e" "w" " " "Y" "o" "r" "k" " " "2" "3" "4" "D" "e" "l" "h" "i" " " " " "b" "e" "r" " " "d" "e" "n" " " "W" "o"
[30] "l" "k" "e" "n" "d" "o" "w" "n" " " "t" "h" "e" " " "s" "t" "r" "a" "e"
 unlist(str_extract_all(txt, "[\\u0000-\\u007f]"))
 [1] "N" "e" "w" " " "Y" "o" "r" "k" " " "2" "3" "4" "D" "e" "l" "h" "i" " " " " "b" "e" "r" " " "d" "e" "n" " " "W" "o"
[30] "l" "k" "e" "n" "d" "o" "w" "n" " " "t" "h" "e" " " "s" "t" "r" "a" "e"
```

I'd be grateful for insight as to why there is this difference between the two character classes.

Comment: PCRE does not support `\u` notation, use `\x{AAAA}`

Comment: Thanks. Why close this post rather than answer it and get points?

Comment: I only close frequent, evident or very narrow questions that are asked regularly. Sorry for that. Still, your question is good.